# How to query for department wise doctor list according to their priority?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Suppose I have two tables `Doctor` & `Doctor_department`

In `Doctor_department` table have some departments

**department list**

> a(priority=1), b(priority=2), c(priority=3)

And In `Doctor` table there also have some doctor list with priority under those departments

**doctor list**

> d1(prority=1, dpearmtent=a), d2(prority=2, dpearmtent=a),
> d3(prority=3, dpearmtent=a), d4(prority=4, dpearmtent=b),
> d5(prority=5, dpearmtent=b), d6(prority=6, dpearmtent=c),
> d7(prority=7, dpearmtent=c)

Now I want to query those doctors according to department and priority like below format

> (a(d1,d2,d3)),(b(d4,d5)),(c(d6,d7))

What is the query for MySQL?

I can fetch doctors list ascending order according to their priority but can't fetch doctor with department in ascending order according to its priority.

**Query**

```
Doctor_list = Doctor::orderBy('priority', 'ASC')->get();
```

Anybody can help please ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You Have two solution here first one make a join between two tables and order by Doctor_department.priority .

The second one I'm suppose  Doctor_department is a pivot table and you have 'departments' table and have relation called doctors with type belongsToMany then you can use code below to retrive all departments sorted by priority and have doctors.

```php
Department::orderBy('priority','ASC')->has('doctors')->with('doctors')->get();
```

Comment: `->has('doctors')->with('doctors')` or `->has('doctors')->with('doctor_department')` ?

Comment: what is name of relation you are defined on departments model ?